# .htaccess redirect only specific types of static content?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I'm looking to redirect any .php file requests to index.php or any requests to directories or static content that dosnt exist should also go to index.php.

This is what I have so far. I'm just not sure how to redirect only .php files and not redirect things like images, css, js

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your shown samples, could you please try following. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

***JS/CS rewrite/redirect:***
You may need to use base tag to fix your js and other relative resources. If you are linking js files using a relative path then the file will obviously get a 404 because its looking for URL path. for example if the URL path is /file/ instead of file.html then your relative resources are loading from /file/ which is not a directory but rewritten html file. To fix this make your links absolute or use base tag. In the header of your webpage add this `<base href="/">` so that your relative links can load from the correct location.

Comment: This works. Thanks for the heads up on the JS/CS but we always use absolute paths for them '/blah/test.js'